# Is there Any way to Edit pre-generated Code in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans6.8

I am newbie to NetBeans.

When I create a new MIDLET program, it automatically generates some code and it is not able to be edited.

How Can I edit these Pre-Defined Codes in NetBeans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge you cannot edit them through Netbeans, but what you can do, is to open the files you would like to edit in some text editor such as Notepad or Notepad++ and do your editing there. The changes should be then visible from Netbeans.